# Is there a Java annotation for noting that a List may contain nulls?

Tags: java, annotations

Is there something like a @ContainsNulls annotation that notes that there may be nulls inside a List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify that a list may contain null elements, declare the list element types using Java's type annotation feature.  For example:

```java
List<@Nullable String> mylist;
```

Many tools exist for checking nullness, and each one defines its own `@Nullable` annotation.  Many of the tools can read and interpret other tools' annotations.

Most of the tools make `@NonNull` the default annotation, so if you just write `List<String>` the tool interprets that as `List<@NonNull String>`.  This choice reduces the clutter in your code.

A list of the different tools and their annotations can be found in the [Checker Framework manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-related-work).

Some of the tools are bug detectors that find *some* null pointer exceptions, and others are verification tools that guarantee that your code has *no* null pointer exceptions.  The right tool for you depends on your situation; here is [a comparison](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#other-tools) of the two types of tools.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that you could put annotations within the generic itself! Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, at least no on Intellij/Java 8.  Perhaps annotating types in a generic came later?

Comment: This does work on Java 8.  Regarding IntelliJ, you need to use a separate tool, the Checker Framework, which the answer links to.  You didn't say what the problem was other than "doesn't seem to work"; did you import the `@Nullable` annotation?

Answer (score 0):

It'll lead to compilation error.

> '@Nullable' not applicable to type use

We can't put @Nullable annotation in type definition. Optional class can help here.

```
List<@Nullable String> mylist;
```